# Javascript is having problems with moving divs around

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

Here's a function:

```
function rollImgOnSwipe(direction) {
    changeDirection(direction);
    rollImage(direction);
}
```

The first called function (`changeDirection(direction);`) is supposed to place a div in either the left or right side of the screen, depending on the value of its argument. The second one (`rollImage(direction);`) is to make the div move from left to right or from right to left, depending on where the first function placed it.

Well, it seems like it first calls `rollImage` and then `changeDirection` because it takes `rollImgOnSwipe` to be called more than once in order for the div to be placed on the other side.

The best way to explain this to you is to show you - run the code snippet and try switching between the divs with the `prev` and `next` buttons and see how they behave.

```js
var nextBtn = document.getElementById('next'),
prevBtn = document.getElementById('prev'),
shown = document.getElementsByClassName('shown')[0],
hidden = document.getElementsByClassName('hidden')[0];

function rollImage(direction) {
shown.classList.remove("shown");
shown.classList.add("hidden");

hidden.classList.remove("hidden");
hidden.classList.add("shown");

shown = document.getElementsByClassName('shown')[0];
hidden = document.getElementsByClassName('hidden')[0];

changeDirection(direction);
}

function rollImgOnSwipe(direction) {
changeDirection(direction);
rollImage(direction);
}

function changeDirection(direction) {
hidden.style.left = (105 * direction) + "%";
shown.style.left = 0;
}

nextBtn.addEventListener('click', function () { rollImgOnSwipe(1); });
prevBtn.addEventListener('click', function () { rollImgOnSwipe(-1); });
```

```css
.img {
position: absolute;
display: block;

width: 80px;
height: 30px;

border-style: solid;
border-color: red;
border-width: 5px;
}

.shown{
left: 0;
transition: left .6s ease, transform .6s ease;
}

.hidden{
left: 105%;
}

.img-wrapper{
position: relative;

width: 80px;
height: 30px;
padding: 30px;

white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<button id="prev">prev</button>

<div class="img-wrapper">
    <div class="img shown"></div>
    <div class="img hidden"></div>
</div>

<button id="next">next</button>
```

To fix this, i make the compiler wait for a bit before calling `rollImage` by using the `setTimeout` function in `rollImgOnSwipe`.

And now the program works as expected:

```js
var nextBtn = document.getElementById('next'),
    prevBtn = document.getElementById('prev'),
    shown = document.getElementsByClassName('shown')[0],
    hidden =  document.getElementsByClassName('hidden')[0];

function rollImage(direction) {
    shown.classList.remove("shown");
    shown.classList.add("hidden");

    hidden.classList.remove("hidden");
    hidden.classList.add("shown");

    shown = document.getElementsByClassName('shown')[0];
    hidden = document.getElementsByClassName('hidden')[0];

    changeDirection(direction);
}

function rollImgOnSwipe(direction) {
    changeDirection(direction);
    setTimeout(function() { rollImage(direction); }, 50);
}

function changeDirection(direction) {
    hidden.style.left = (105 * direction) + "%";
    shown.style.left = 0;
}

nextBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){ rollImgOnSwipe(1); });
prevBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){ rollImgOnSwipe(-1); });
```

```css
.img {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;

    width: 80px;
    height: 30px;

    border-style: solid;
    border-color: red;
    border-width: 5px;
}

.shown{
    left: 0;
    transition: left .6s ease, transform .6s ease;
}

.hidden{
    left: 105%;
}

.img-wrapper{
    position: relative;

    width: 80px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 30px;

    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<button id="prev">prev</button>

<div class="img-wrapper">
    <div class="img shown"></div>
    <div class="img hidden"></div>
</div>

<button id="next">next</button>
```

My question is:

What is the problem and why is it fixed by making the compiler wait?

Comment: You should use CSS transitions to move things around, not JS.

Comment: Could it be because you are calling changeDirection from rollImgOnSwipe, and then calling it again from within rollImage?  What happens if you get rid of the call to changeDirection that's in rollImage?

Comment: @Amy I'll consider it, thank you.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be it, @James , thank You. That's the first part of the question answered.